Definitions of argument notation for relations
Is there a standard definition for relation argument notation $R(x)$, for some relation $R \subseteq A \times B$, and if not what are the different definitions used, or at least where can I read about it?
We sometimes define images (sets) as $R[X]$ where $X$ is a set, but what I am curious about is the specific use of it. For example, we might use the (non-principal) square root $\sqrt{ x }$, to say something like $\sqrt{ x } = y$ or maybe in the context of setbuilder notation $\{ x | R(x) = y \}$.
To be more specific the answer I am looking for is a formal (maybe logic) definition of the properties or use of $R(x)$.
My intuition is that $R(x)$ cannot be formally defined and is more of a notation thing; if that is the case, I am curious about how one would denote it in different contexts without using $R(x)$. And if this is very dependent on the author, I am curious about the various meanings different authors have used.
So forexample for $\sqrt{ x } = y$ we might say $y \in \{ y' | (y')^2 = x \}$. And for sets, we might have that $\{ x | R(x) = y \}$ is the same as writing $\{ x | x R y \}$.
